# Email forwarding on MacOS w Homebrew

Tags: email, macos

On my Debian boxes, I installed postfix which forwards my local mails (ie from cron) to my service account on my mailserver. So postfix is configured to use my mailserver as a relay. This works pretty fine for all my Debian hosts.

Now I realized my Mac with Homebrew also creates local emails. I am getting "You have new mail" when opening a terminal.

Is there a way to configure my local Mac to relay/ forward all these mails to my mailserver instead of collecting them locally? Postfix is not available through Homebrew.

Comment: Postfix/sendmail is installed by default in macOS. I just tried with `mail foo@example.com` and was able to send a mail.

Answer (score 2):

@nohillside:
You made my day!

I removed all above entriees from main.cf leaving it at the MacOS defaults.

Then I simply created the .forward file which contains a single line:
`admin@mydomain.com`

Now every mail get send to my postfix relay host even though I am wondering why I do not need to SASL-Authenticate. But this is a different issue.

Thanks a lot!
Working now (hopefully, waiting for the next cron emails).

[Update] I had issues with the authentication as my postfix requires authentication but looks like the MacOS postfix did not use it. In the end I changed the `/private/etc/postfix/main.cf`so I added the following (I needed to add the both tls options!):

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:{relayuser:FxZdH§%xcEFFG+}
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
relayhost = [mylocal.mailserver.com]:587
```

Comment: Is this an actual key after relayuser?

Comment: Of course not ;) It is not even the real username :)